# Sql query for sum(field) with order by anotherfield and limit

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

I am having the below table name 'banking'

```
+------------------------------+
|    id | amount | created     |
+------------------------------+
| 1 | 10 | 2018-01-18 00:10:00 |
| 2 | 20 | 2018-01-18 00:50:00 |
| 3 | 30 | 2018-01-18 00:20:00 |
| 4 | 40 | 2018-01-18 00:30:00 |
+------------------------------+
```

and I need an output as 60

I have tried this query

```
SELECT sum(amount) 
  FROM banking 
 WHERE created >= '2018-01-18 00:00:00' 
   AND created < '2018-01-18 18:01:35' 
 GROUP 
    BY created
 ORDER 
    BY created DESC LIMIT 2;
```

but I get an out put as

```
+---------+
|   | sum |
+---------+
| 1 | 20  |
| 2 | 40  |
+---------+
```

how do I get singlescalar output as 60 (the sum of 40+20)

Comment: How will you get 60? I see that all your records qualify as per your where clause - `created >= '2018-01-18 00:00:00' AND created < '2018-01-18 18:01:35'`

Comment: yes all my records qualified but I need to limit the sum by 2 so that i expect the result as 60

Comment: Got it. Check the answer below.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The LIMIT seems very arbitrary.

Comment: I am trying to get only 2 result by order desc a created filed in four results

Comment: How is accepted answer is different from what I answered below? Why all the remaining answers have been downvoted? This is SO, not FB. Not accepting the answers due to lack of clarity is fine but who gives the privilege to downvote the correct answers?

Comment: @YusufHassan The accepted answer differs from the other answers provided. The other answers are incorrect.

Comment: @Strawberry I can't figure out how my solution is wrong. The answer is still un-edited and with a SDL Fiddle link attached for verification.

Comment: @YusufHassan OK, maybe not wrong. Just redundant. And if there was more than one entry created at the same time, then it would be wrong. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ea4f4/1

Comment: Tag properly!!!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server <> PosgresSQL.  Which one are you using?????

Answer (score -1):

This should suffice:

```
select sum(amount) from
(SELECT sum(amount) amount FROM banking 
WHERE created >= '2018-01-18 00:00:00' AND created < '2018-01-18 18:01:35' 
GROUP BY created ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 2)sum_amount;
```

Check the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b24a/3)**